# gnome-ppp conflicts with resolvconf

Tags: gnome, usb-modem, modem

`gnome-ppp` package shows the following error in installation:

```
Conflicts with already installed package resolvconf
```

`wvdial` is already installed and all its dependencies are satisfied.

Comment: There was a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-ppp/+bug/585744) which has been fixed. Which Ubuntu release are you using?

Answer (score -2):

You should use GTK PPP: https://sourceforge.net/p/gtk-ppp/ (new gtk3 version of GNOME PPP)

Comment: -1 Entirely unrelated to OP's question.